# Error Transfer: A source Connection must be specified SSIS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssis

I am trying to transfer data from Oracle to MSSQL via SSIS. I created ODBC source from Oracle and then Data conversion to OLE DB source. But I have the following errors:

> Error at Transfer: A source connection must be specified.
>   Error at
>   Transfer: A destination connection must be specified.

[image: Error]

Please tell me how can remove the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look closely at the error message.

> Error at **Transfer HDM [Transfer Database Task]**: A source connection
>   must be specified.

It's likely that you have another task on your Control Flow for the package you are trying to execute that is failing validation because it doesn't have any connection set. Move back to the control flow view and check for error icons or a task called "Transfer HDM [Transfer Database Task]" and make sure it's correctly configured.

An alternative is to disable the task that's giving you errors: it won't execute nor try to validate connections or metadata. Another option would be executing only the task you want to execute by right clicking with "Execute Task".